# Git python API returns invalid branch name when using tag

Tags: git, python-2.7, git-branch, gitpython

I am trying to checkout a branch with a tag that references a commit. I keep getting an error that the branch name is invalid because it is trying to take the tag name as part of my branch. I am using GitPython which is just using the python git api

the tag name is `v1.1`

`self.repo.git.checkout("-b test_1.1 v1.1")`

This is the failure I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "base.py", line 126, in <module>
    x.checkoutVersion()
  File "base.py", line 118, in checkoutVersion
    self.repo.git.checkout("-b test_1.1 v1.1")
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/git/cmd.py", line 545, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: self._call_process(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/git/cmd.py", line 1014, in _call_process
    return self.execute(call, **exec_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/git/cmd.py", line 825, in execute
    raise GitCommandError(command, status, stderr_value, stdout_value)
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128)
  cmdline: git checkout -b test_1.1 v1.1
  stderr: 'fatal: ' test_1.1 v1.1' is not a valid branch name.'
```

I can run this command fine in the terminal, I don't know why it is failing when run through the API

I am using Python 2.7.10

Comment: Looks like you're misusing the `git.checkout` function: see p. 17 of https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/gitpython/stable/gitpython.pdf

Comment: Yupp, you're right. Read that I can just pass a string with options but that was not correct. Changed command to `self.repo.git.checkout("v1.1", b="test_1.1")`

Answer (score 0):

You could try and separate the arguments, as shown in "[Switching branches](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#switching-branches)":

```
self.repo.git.checkout('-b', 'test_1.1', 'v1.1')
```